# SWT ShellEvent source attribute

Tags: java, swt

#### Background

I am currently debugging an issue in an application using Eclipse [GEF](https://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Description), in which a UI component loses focus to another when it shouldn't.

In order to investigate the cause, I created listeners for `shellActivated` and `shellDeactivated`. The listeners receive a `ShellEvent` object providing information about the event.

#### Question

Where can I find documentation about what information is contained in the `ShellEvent` object?  In particular, what does the `source` attribute contain? It looks something like

```
source  Shell (id=13713)
[0] AnnotationEditFloatingToolbar (id=13753)
[1] Foo$Bar(id=13754)
[2] Text (id=13755)
[3] Foo$Bar(id=13756)
[4] Text (id=13757)
[5] Qux(id=13758)
```

Can I interpret this as the path the event took when bubbling through nested components?

Comment: That isn't the sort of output I get testing the source value - how are you producing this output? The `source` field is just the widget that produced the event (in this case the Shell)

Comment: That was via Eclipse's "Variables" view on a breakpoint in the handler. I find the display rather confusing so I'm not even sure what data structure I'm looking at. In any case, the widget that produces the event is the one losing/gaining focus, correct?

Comment: It is the Shell that you added the listener to. The one that is being activated / deactivated. The [0]... items are just the controls that are children of the Shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `source` field for `ShellEvent` is just the `Shell` which is producing the event. The is the same value as the `widget` field.

In the debug variables view the [0]... items are just the controls which are children of the shell. This is nothing to do with the 'path' of the event.